# I get "Can't install application" error in XCode when trying to run my application on my iPhone for debug

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I get `Can't install application` error in XCode when trying to run my application on my iPhone for debug. I use XCode 7 that allows to test applications directly on devices without apple developer subscription. Here is the full error text:

> Application iOS.app cannot be installed on iPhone. Application iOS.app can only be installed on iPads.

Comment: You app is an iPad only app, change it to either universal (iPhone and iPad) or to iPhone only.

Comment: How can I do that? I changed the device family to "1,2", but it did not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your app compatible with iPhone. Open project settings, select Target and your app name, then go to General tab and change Devices to Universal.

[image]